# How can I only let a specific frequency pass in an AM receiver?

Tags: rf, radio, low-pass, amplitude-modulation, high-pass-filter

I wanted to create an AM receiver and I know partly how to demodulate the signal. I know I need to use a low pass filter to get the low frequency audio signal, but I don't know how to only get data from a specific frequency. I think I can just use one low pass filter and one high pass filter to pick the frequency, but that would require two capacitors and normally AM radios have only one variable capacitor.

This is what the low pass and high pass filter circuit, I thought about, looks.

Note: The input is a sine wave and it has no data attached to it. There just wasn't a proper AM signal generator. I am also assuming the signal frequency is 40Hz in the calculations.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZqXZC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Can you show your design? Yes, you need only one variable capacitor for HF, the other filtering is typically done on the NF side, where the filter can be static.

Comment: @PMF I added the circuit diagram to the description.

Comment: Have you looked at any existing/standard designs for simple AM receivers? How does your circuit compare to those?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the schematic of a simple AM crystal radio.

[image]

It's parallel-resonant circuit selects the specific frequency that is to be demodulated.

Comment: Do I need to have a sine wave oscillator on the circuit, or is a square wave oscillator enough.

Comment: A square wave oscillator would do.

Comment: Is it possible to not use an inductor?

Comment: No. An inductor and a capacitor are a must for resonance in order to select the desired frequency.

Comment: But would my circuit work?

Comment: The first low-pass filter will pass frequencies below 1 kHz, the high-pass filter those above 1.5 kHz and the second low-pass filter those below 40 Hz. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I messed the filters up, but basically I wanted to block any signals above 1.5 kHz and below 0.5 kHz. The second low pass filter is allowing just the low frequency data signal that is sent with the carrier signal.

Comment: Presuming you get your filters right, you still need to tune in to the specific frequency in the 0.5 - 1.5 kHz band. The 'Simple AM Crystal Radio' is good enough for your purpose. Here's a good resource for you - https://www.mikroe.com/ebooks/radio-receivers-from-crystal-set-to-stereo/the-simplest-radio-receiver

Comment: Your very simple filters DO NOT BLOCK higher and lower frequencies, instead the filters simply reduce the levels of the higher and lower frequencies. The fullwave rectifier feeding the filters messes up the filtering. The filters need a power amplifier to feed the speaker.

Comment: @Audioguru - Hi, I suppose your comment is intended for the OP!